# Remove formula in cell using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have made two vba codes.

1. For doing round off on selected cell. Working fine
2. For undoing round off on selected cells. This has a little issue. After i do this it make the cells isformula true. But i dont want to make formula of constant numeric values. For example, you see in cell A1 there is = sign that makes it isformula true but i dont want to put equal sign here. In cell A3 i have another formula so i want = sign. What should i change in vba code? See pictures i uploaded. Thanks
   [image: image 1]
   [image: image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your code after the line `h = Replace(g, ",2)", "")`

```vba
    If IsNumeric(Mid(h, 2, 1)) Then
        h = Replace(h, "=", "")
    End If
```

It check if the character after the `=` is numeric. If yes, the `=` is removed.
Your code will be:

```
Sub UndoRoundOff()

    Dim x As Range

    For Each x In Selection
        f = x.Formula
        g = Replace(f, "=ROUND(", "=")
        h = Replace(g, ",2)", "")
    
        If IsNumeric(Mid(h, 2, 1)) Then
            h = Replace(h, "=", "")
        End If
    
        x.Formula = h

    Next x

End Sub
```